# How can I test flagged transaction response in test environment in Checkout.com

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, payment, checkout

I am using [Checkout.com](https://archive.docs.checkout.com/docs/flags) for payment processing. I want to test flagged transaction response in a test environment.

How can I get this response in test mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flagging a transaction is an action that is taken by a Risk Rule in Checkout.com

To be able to flag a transaction you simply need to set a risk rule in your Checkout.com Hub and trigger this risk rule in your payment request.

For example, you can set up a "threshold" risk rule that will flag a transaction if it exceeds (or it's bellow) a certain amount.

[image]

After setting up this, sending a payment request with a value that will trigger the risk rule, will result in a flagged response from the API.

You can also see some sample responses in the [API Reference of Checkout.com](https://api-reference.checkout.com/#tag/Payments/paths/~1payments/post)

Here is a sample:

```
{
"id": "pay_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea",
"action_id": "act_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea",
"amount": 20000,
"currency": "USD",
"approved": true,
"status": "Authorized",
"auth_code": "290947",
"eci": "05",
"scheme_id": "638284745624527",
"response_code": "10000",
"response_summary": "Approved",
"risk": {
    "flagged": true
},
"source": {
    // dynamic based on your source
},
"customer": {
    "id": "cus_vh2hq53yioouvg3etkuw2xdhcu",
    "name": "Sarah Mitchell"
},
"processed_on": "2019-06-25T18:27:10Z",
"reference": "ORD-5023-4E89",
"processing": {
    "acquirer_transaction_id": "8138182777",
    "retrieval_reference_number": "000290947597"
},
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.checkout.com/payments/pay_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea"
    },
    "actions": {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.checkout.com/payments/pay_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea/actions"
    },
    "capture": {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.checkout.com/payments/pay_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea/captures"
    },
    "void": {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.checkout.com/payments/pay_jf7xoknmva3upbatzkiqcwvkea/voids"
    }
}
}
```

Notice the:

```
"risk": {
  "flagged": true
},
```